# Can a god have more than one blessed vessel?

Tags: noragami

Lord Yato has Yukine (Sekki) as his blessed vessel aka. his exemplar and Lord Bishamonten has Kazuma as her blessed vessel aka. an exemplar.

Can a god have more than one blessed vessel?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes.

I would say that it is possible for a god to have more than one hafuri, because to be a hafuri only means to attempt to sacrifice one's name for their master. I don't believe there is a limitation on that, however as far as I know there can only be one exemplar/guidepost. Exemplars and blessed vessels are different though (as Takemikazuchi reminds us frequently).

In one arc (**warning: manga spoiler!**),

> Bishamon makes Nana, who was a legendary blessed vessel imprisoned by heaven, her shinki, so it is possible for a god to have more than one hafuri. However, Nana changed and became a hafuri for her original master and not Bishamon, so there is no definite proof.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]! This site is a Q&A site about anime & manga, and we're a bit different than other discussion forums. Consider taking a quick [tour] to understand more how this site works. You can also use `>!` to add spoiler markdown.